# Why this program for finding prime numbers outputs both answers?

Tags: java

This Code works properly for numbers upto 4 but then prints wrong or sometimes both, "Number is Prime" and "not Prime".

```java
package timepass;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Timepass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the no :");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
                
        if (n==1 || n==0) {
            System.out.println("It is not a prime no"); 
        } 
        else if (n > 1) {
            for(int i = 2; i<n; i++) {
                if (n % i ==0) {
                    System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
                    break;
                    
                } else {
                    System.out.println("It is a prime number"); 
                }
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide examples of numbers that (it says) are both prime and non-prime.

Comment: Look at your `else` statement inside `for` loop. When the `if` condition fails, it'll always print *It is a prime number* for every iteration. You can use a `boolean` flag which can be updated when `n%i == 0` condition satisfies. Then once the loop exits, you can check finally whether your number is prime or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is slight mistake in the logic.

You have to check all the integers from `2` to `n-1`, if they are factors of `n` and then make the final verdict.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Timepass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the no :");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
                
        if (n==1 || n==0) {
            System.out.println("It is not a prime no"); 
        } 
        else if (n > 1) {
            
            boolean isPrime = true;
            
            for(int i = 2; i<n; i++) {
                if (n % i ==0) {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            
            if(isPrime) {
                System.out.println("It is a prime number"); 
            }else{
                System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

**PS:** Also search for more efficient logics to check if the number is prime. For example: In the above code, their is no need to iterate from `2` until `n-1`. You can stop at `n/2`.

Comment: Good answer. And, if you only iterate `i` to the ceiling of square root of `n`, this would be perfect for an algorithm that does not take advantage of high level prime tests IMHO. UV!

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem.

Hint: a number is prime if there are no factors.  Your code is printing "prime" when >>a<< number is not a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example 5 and your loop.

```
2: not a factor, print "It is a prime number"
3: not a factor, print "It is a prime number"
4: not a factor, print "It is a prime number"
```

When can you as a human tell that it is a prime number? Surely not already at 2.
(Actually you can at 3, but your loop condition is inefficient....)

So why do you print already? You should not.

Look at 9:

```
2: not a factor, print "It is a prime number" 
3: is a factor, print "It is not a prime number"; break, stop looping
```

Again, at 2 you do not know yet but print anyway; at three you know and stop.

The solution is to print in all cases only when leaving the loop. You do so correctly before the break for "not prime". But you print several times for "prime", possibly wrongly and possibly later again for "not prime".
The point to print "prime" is after going through all of the loop without finding a factor.
Make sure that you do not do that printing after leaving the loop with break for "not prime". You can do so by introducing a function which does the prime check and returns a value indicating the result. That function can return where you currently break and after the loop. Then print the result text from the calling code, based on the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a flag variable in order to check the number whether it is prime or not. The problem with your case is that everytime it check if the number is divisible by i and if this condition becomes false then it goes to the else condition and prints 'not prime' and this is wrong the program should wait for the loop to end and then it should print any result.
So use a flag variable, initialize it false and if the number is divisible by any value of i then make the value of flag true and break out of loop.
After the loop check for flag variable and if the variable is true print not prime else prime .

Answer (score -1):

//you can use flag instead of printing the massage inside the for loop
// if flag is true means the number is not a prime number

```
boolean flag = false; 
 for(int i =2; i< n; i++){
    if(n % i ==0){
      flag = true;
      break;
   }
 }
 if (flag) {
  System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
 } else {
  System.out.println("It is a prime number"); 
 }
```

Comment: Poor answer.  You should at least attempt to explain your code.  (In this case, it would help you understand why this solution it is incorrect.)

Answer (score -2):

import java.util.Scanner;

class Timepass {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the no :");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
            
    if (n==1 || n==0) {
        System.out.println("It is not a prime no"); 
    } 
    else if (n > 1) {
        for(int i = 2; i<n; i++) {
            if (n % i ==0) {
                System.out.println("It is not a prime number");
                break;
                
            } else {
                System.out.println("It is a prime number"); 
                break;
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

}

Comment: Please add description and format the code.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It would also help more if the code was correct :-)